# could not resolve org.apache.hcatalog.pig.hcatloader using imports

Tags: apache-pig, oozie, hue, hcatalog

I am trying to create a workflow with just one pig action, I have all the jars available in the path **/user/oozie/share/lib/lib_*** and also I am defining the path of **hive-site.xml** in the job nodes.

But the job fails saying :

could not resolve `org.apache.hcatalog.pig.hcatloader` using imports

Please help

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to use `org.apache.hive.hcatalog.pig.HCatLoader` instead of `org.apache.hcatalog.pig.hcatloader`
from [the link](http://hive.apache.org/javadocs/r0.13.1/api/hcatalog/hcatalog-pig-adapter/org/apache/hcatalog/pig/HCatLoader.html)

Comment: Hi Thanks,
But am running into another one 
Error :
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/facebook/fb303/FacebookS

Note : I am not using any customer UDFS here

Comment: By any chance do you have more than different versions of thrift and libthrift hanging around? It sounds like the classes are being generated with one version of thrift, but trying to use a different version of libthrift at runtime.

Comment: The above error has been resolved or not (Asked in the question)

Comment: Yes, The above issue got resolved after upgrading my java version..
Previously my java version was 1.6 in all the nodes.
I have upgraded it to java 1.8.

Comment: Accept answer if it helped u...It will help others in future

Comment: One more thing to clarify is that in older version of hadoop cluster this "org.apache.hcatalog.pig.hcatloader" was working fine. Is it Because of cluster upgradation that i had to change to "org.apache.hive.hcatalog.pig.HCatLoader"